# jquery_datepicker not working with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-ui-datepicker, rails-4-upgrade

See the following repo for example project: https://github.com/aarona/date_picker

At first I thought the problem was caused by the model being tableless but when associating it with the database through a migration I still get an error:

`wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

on this line:

```
<%= f.datepicker :start_date,  :class => 'short' %>
```

I get an error about `delete` method not found if the model is tableless.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the gem `jquery_datepicker` is incompatible with Rails 4. Time to use a different gem/control if I want to upgrade.

A solution is available for Rails 4+. You can find this solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43289610/43792