# Couldn't find file 'jquery-ui/datepicker' with type 'application/javascript' in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datepicker

I've this app in ruby on rails framework and have one of a form field of date_select. I wanted to add datepicker of jquery in this  date_select field using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329381/how-do-i-connect-jquery-datepicker-to-my-ruby-on-rails-form) link but nothing seems to work for me.

I've jquery-ui version 4.2.1 but still I'm getting error of **Couldn't find file 'jquery-ui/datepicker' with type 'application/javascript'  in rails**

Here's my `app\assets\javascripts\application.js`-

```
// some written text-

//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
```

Here's my `app\assets\stylesheets\application.css`

```
/*
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*= require jquery-ui/datepicker
*/
```

Here's my form-field in one of the controller view-

```
<%= form.text_field(:dateneed, id: :order_dateneed, :class=>'form-control mb-1') %>
```

and finally here's my coffee script of one of the controller-

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('#order_dateneed').datepicker
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
```

I'm tired since morning of trying all things from degrading version of jquery-ui-rails from 5.0 to 4.2.1 but still there's no datepicker in my text_field of date. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your link you need to install gem in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

(run `bundle` after this)

Also write in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

```
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
```

And in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`:

```
*= require jquery.ui.datepicker
```

(you wrote via dash)

Comment: It didn't work, I'm not getting an error but datepicker doesn't appear there. Id of field is also correct

Comment: The most frustrated moment happened with me, I was trying to resolve the issue from last 6-8 hours and finally found that I forgot to add the jquery cdn plugin in my application.html.erb (-_-)